# translate values in dataprovider for a datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, dataprovider

I have a dataprovider that is an ArrayCollection of simple string values. I need to get these strings translated before they are rendered in my datagrid. How can I do this?

Note that I do not want to copy it to a new ArrayCollection with the translated values since i allowing inline editing to update the dataprovider source.

Current datagrid without translation for values in the dataprovider

```
<mx:DataGrid width="100%" height="100%" id="contactInfoGrid"
                                 dataProvider="{model.selectedCustomer.contacts}"
                                 editable="true" itemEditEnd="contactInfoChanged(event)">
                        <mx:columns>
                            <mx:DataGridColumn width="200" dataField="type" editable="false"
                                               headerText="{resourceManager.getString('customer','customer.contactInformation.type')}"/>
                            <mx:DataGridColumn width="300" dataField="value" editable="true"
                                               headerText="{resourceManager.getString('customer','customer.contactInformation.value')}"/>
                            <mx:DataGridColumn editable="false" headerText="{resourceManager.getString('customer','general.remove')}">
                                <mx:itemRenderer>
                                    <mx:Component>
                                        <mx:VBox horizontalAlign="center">
                                            <controls:RemoveLinkButton visible="true" label=""  click="outerDocument.removeContactInfo(event)"/>
                                        </mx:VBox>
                                    </mx:Component>
                                </mx:itemRenderer>
                            </mx:DataGridColumn> 
                        </mx:columns>
                    </mx:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will either need to:

- translate the values in the dataprovider itself. I'm not sure if you want to do this as you will change the source of data.
- add label functions to the datagrid columns and return the translated text for each cell